# Merge objects according to their keys and values

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

*I have edited the original question as the example did not make the desired output clear, namely I did not specify that I needed the strings that are common with the object that matches the `Rank`*

I am trying to merge an array of objects into a single object

There are three sets of `keys` per `object`, I would like to have just one instance of each set with its lowest number for the `Rank` value or if the `Rank` equals '-' on all objects.

```js
let objs = [
  {
    Keyword: 'A keyword',
    'First Rank': '-',
    'First Title': '-',
    'First URL': '-',
    'Second Rank': '-',
    'Second Title': '-',
    'Second URL': '-',
    'Third Rank': 1,
    'Third Title': 'Title for 1',
    'Third URL': 'https://for-one.example.com'
  },
  {
    Keyword: 'A keyword',
    'First Rank': '-',
    'First Title': '-',
    'First URL': '-',
    'Second Rank': 2,
    'Second Title': 'Title for 2',
    'Second URL': 'https://for-two.example.com',
    'Third Rank': '-',
    'Third Title': '-',
    'Third URL': '-'
  },
  {
    Keyword: 'A keyword',
    'First Rank': '-',
    'First Title': '-',
    'First URL': '-',
    'Second Rank': '-',
    'Second Title': '-',
    'Second URL': '-',
    'Third Rank': 7,
    'Third Title': 'Title for 7',
    'Third URL': 'https://for-seven.example.com'
  }
]

// I have managed to get the ones with values with this:


const clean = objs.reduce((acc, object) => {
  const clone = (({ Keyword, ...obj }) => obj)(object)

  if (Object.values(clone).some(val => val !== '-')) {
    Object.keys(clone).forEach(key => object[key] === '-' && delete object[key])
    acc.push(object)
  }

  return acc
}, [])

const merged = clean.reduce((result, current) => ({ ...current, ...result }), {})

console.log(merged)
```

But I am struggling to add the one with no values, it should look like this:

```
{
  'Keyword': 'A keyword',
  'First Rank': '-',
  'First Title': '-',
  'First URL': '-',
  'Second Rank': 2,
  'Second Title': 'Title for 2',
  'Second URL': 'https://for-two.example.com',
  'Third Rank': 1,
  'Third Title': 'Title for 1',
  'Third URL': 'https://for-one.example.com'
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who answered this question, however I did not explain in detail some requirements and when I did it was too late to get a follow up response, so I made my own, I am sure there is a better way to do it, but this works.

```js
let objs = [
  {
    'Keyword': 'A keyword',
    'First Rank': '-',
    'First Title': '-',
    'First URL': '-',
    'Second Rank': '-',
    'Second Title': '-',
    'Second URL': '-',
    'Third Rank': 1,
    'Third Title': 'Title for 1',
    'Third URL': 'https://for-one.example.com'
  },
  {
    'Keyword': 'A keyword',
    'First Rank': '-',
    'First Title': '-',
    'First URL': '-',
    'Second Rank': 2,
    'Second Title': 'Title for 2',
    'Second URL': 'https://for-two.example.com',
    'Third Rank': '-',
    'Third Title': '-',
    'Third URL': '-'
  },
  {
    'Keyword': 'A keyword',
    'First Rank': '-',
    'First Title': '-',
    'First URL': '-',
    'Second Rank': '-',
    'Second Title': '-',
    'Second URL': '-',
    'Third Rank': 7,
    'Third Title': 'Title for 7',
    'Third URL': 'https://for-seven.example.com'
  }
]

// Remove dashed entries and keep only the ones with data
const removeDashed = objs.reduce((acc, object) => {
  // Clone object except for the keyword key
  const clone = (({ Keyword, ...obj }) => obj)(object)
  if (Object.values(clone).some(val => val !== '-')) {
    Object.keys(object).forEach(key => object[key] === '-' && delete object[key])
    acc.push(object)
  }
  return acc
}, [])

// Merge array into a single object with first entries found first
const merged = removeDashed.reduce((result, current) => ({ ...current, ...result }), {})

// Items that should be present
const items = ['First', 'Second', 'Third']

// Get the existing keys from the unique obj
const keys = Object.keys(merged).map(key => key.split(' ')[0])

// If one or more items are missing insert them and add dashed values
items.forEach(item => {
  if (!keys.includes(item)) {
    merged[`${item} Rank`] = '-'
    merged[`${item} Title`] = '-'
    merged[`${item} URL`] = '-'
  }
})

// Sort function to reorder | thanks to Soc for this
const sorting = item => (a, b) => {
  const alphaOrder = a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0

  if (a === 'Keyword') return -1
  if (b === 'Keyword') return 1
  if (a.startsWith(item) && b.startsWith(item)) return alphaOrder
  if (a.startsWith(item)) return -1
  if (b.startsWith(item)) return 1

  return alphaOrder
}

// Implement the sorting
const result = Object.keys(merged)
  .sort(sorting(items[0]))
  .reduce((acc, current) => {
    acc[current] = merged[current]
    return acc
  }, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could reduce the array and check the key of the entries.

```js
let array = [{ 'Keyword': 'A keyword', 'First URL': '-', 'First Rank': '-', 'First Title': '-', 'Second URL': '-', 'Second Rank': '-', 'Second Title': '-', 'Third URL': '-', 'Third Rank': '-', 'Third Title': '-' }, { 'Keyword': 'A keyword', 'First URL': '-', 'First Rank': '-', 'First Title': '-', 'Second URL': '-', 'Second Rank': '-', 'Second Title': '-', 'Third URL': 'https://for-seven.example.com', 'Third Rank': 7, 'Third Title': 'Title' }, { 'Keyword': 'A keyword', 'First URL': '-', 'First Rank': '-', 'First Title': '-', 'Second URL': 'https://for-eleven.example.com', 'Second Rank': 11, 'Second Title': 'Title', 'Third URL': '-', 'Third Rank': '-', 'Third Title': '-' }, { 'Keyword': 'A keyword', 'First URL': '-', 'First Rank': '-', 'First Title': '-', 'Second URL': '-', 'Second Rank': '-', 'Second Title': '-', 'Third URL': 'https://for-one.example.com', 'Third Rank': 1, 'Third Title': 'Title' }],
    merged = array.reduce(({ ...r }, o) => {
        var prefix = ['First', 'Second', 'Third'].find(k => o[k + ' Rank'] !== '-'),
            rank = prefix + ' Rank';

        if (r[rank] < o[rank]) return;
        ['URL', 'Rank', 'Title'].forEach(k => {
            var key = `${prefix} ${k}`
            r[key] = o[key];
        });
        return r;
    });
    
console.log(merged);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: But this does not reproduce the desired output, I need the `First` set of keys there too with the value '-'

Comment: What's the purpose of this `{ ...r }`?

Comment: Avoiding mutation?

Comment: @Nina Scholz Now it works but it does not take the lowest `Rank Value` it takes the highest, If I add another obj with `Third Rank` value set to 1 it still takes the one with 7

Comment: what is lowest and highest? a value of same group of first/second/third? do you have only one group in an object?

Comment: @ele, it spreads an object into an object, like a copy of the object.

Comment: @NinaScholz as in 'Third Rank': 1 is lower than 'Third Rank': 7, I have updated the question, I guess you could say highest rank but I meant lowest value

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```js
let objs = [
  {
    'Keyword': 'A keyword',
    'First URL': '-',
    'First Rank': '-',
    'First Title': '-',
    'Second URL': '-',
    'Second Rank': '-',
    'Second Title': '-',
    'Third URL': '-',
    'Third Rank': '-',
    'Third Title': '-'
  },
  {
    'Keyword': 'A keyword',
    'First URL': '-',
    'First Rank': '-',
    'First Title': '-',
    'Second URL': '-',
    'Second Rank': '-',
    'Second Title': '-',
    'Third URL': 'https://example.com',
    'Third Rank': 7,
    'Third Title': 'Title'
  },
  {
    'Keyword': 'A keyword',
    'First URL': '-',
    'First Rank': '-',
    'First Title': '-',
    'Second URL': 'https://example.com',
    'Second Rank': 11,
    'Second Title': 'Title',
    'Third URL': '-',
    'Third Rank': '-',
    'Third Title': '-'
  },
  {
    'Keyword': 'A keyword',
    'First URL': '-',
    'First Rank': '-',
    'First Title': '-',
    'Second URL': '-',
    'Second Rank': '-',
    'Second Title': '-',
    'Third URL': 'https://example.com',
    'Third Rank': 1,
    'Third Title': 'Title overwritten'
  },
]


var result = objs.slice().reduce((acc, item, index) => {
  resultItem = acc.find(accItem => accItem['Keyword'] === item['Keyword']);
  if (!resultItem) {
    acc.push(item)
  } else {
    Object.keys(resultItem).map(k => {
      if (item[k] !== '-') {
        if (typeof item[k] === 'number') {
          resultItem[k] = resultItem[k] === '-' ? item[k] : Math.min(item[k], resultItem[k]);
        } else {
          resultItem[k] = item[k];
        }
      }
    })
  }
  return acc;  
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, but still not taking the lowest `Rank` value, if we add another obj with a lower rank value say to 1 on the `Second Rank` set it would still take the one with 11

Comment: ok, I'll update it. how is should behave with strings? should it take the first or the last or what?

Comment: I am updating the question, the strings should be ignore it is just the `Rank` key that matters

Comment: I also updaed the answer, loot at the `Third Title`. How it should behave in case of my example, should Third Title be 'Title overwritten' o just 'Title' ?

Comment: Actually I think I made a mistake, the string does matter, it has to be related to the object that belongs to that `Rank` I did some tests and I can see that I am getting the rank from the lowest number but the title from another object

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce and within the handler check for the number value in order to compare which is the lowest between the two values.

*In this code snippet there is an additional object with `Third Rank = 1`*

```js
let array = [{ Keyword: 'A keyword', 'First URL': '-', 'First Rank': '-', 'First Title': '-', 'Second URL': '-', 'Second Rank': '-', 'Second Title': '-', 'Third URL': '-', 'Third Rank': '-', 'Third Title': '-' }, { Keyword: 'A keyword', 'First URL': '-', 'First Rank': '-', 'First Title': '-', 'Second URL': '-', 'Second Rank': '-', 'Second Title': '-', 'Third URL': 'https://example.com', 'Third Rank': 7, 'Third Title': '2 third title' }, { Keyword: 'A keyword', 'First URL': '-', 'First Rank': '-', 'First Title': '-', 'Second URL': 'https://example.com', 'Second Rank': 11, 'Second Title': '3 Second title', 'Third URL': '-', 'Third Rank': '-', 'Third Title': '-' }, { Keyword: 'A keyword', 'First URL': '-', 'First Rank': '-', 'First Title': '-', 'Second URL': 'https://example.com', 'Second Rank': 11, 'Second Title': '3 Second title', 'Third URL': '-', 'Third Rank': 1, 'Third Title': '-' }],
    merged = array.reduce(({ ...r }, o) => {
        Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => {
            if (v !== '-') {
              if (isNaN(+v) || isNaN(+r[k])) r[k] = v;
              else r[k] = Math.min(+r[k], +v);
            }
        });
        return r;
    });
    
console.log(merged);
```

Comment: @Álvaro yw `(:`

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake on the example, the final object has to have the `Rank` `Title` and `URL` that belong to that selected object, I am getting the lowest number from `Rank` but the URL and title from another object